# How to remove PAGE SUM in Views Calc?

Tags: views

How can I remove the `Page SUM` row in my Views Calc?

I have upgraded [Views Calc](https://drupal.org/project/views_calc) module to its latest version.

Comment: After doing some trial and error, I have solved my problem.

You can remove the Page SUM in the Views Calc table by using CSS.

`td.view-subfooter{
display: none;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in two ways

1) Add following style in your CSS

```
tr.view-subfooter-number{ display: none; }
```

**OR**

2) Go to  *views-calc-table.tpl.php* file under **views_calc** module directory and find the following code (PAGE SUM row code)

```
  <tr class="view-subfooter-number">
    <?php foreach ($row as $field => $content): ?>
      <td class="view-subfooter views-field views-field-<?php print $fields[$field]; ?>  <?php print $options['info'][$field]['align'] ?>">
        <?php print $content; ?>
      </td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tr>
```

You can comment/remove the above code to hide 'PAGE SUM' row at view output.

Comment: 2) if you are going to edit a .tpl.php, best to copy it to your theme folder first ! that way you are overriding it and you still have the original.

Answer (score 1):

As the page sum is used with the *pager*, therefore it should really *only* appear when using a pager so:

copy the `views-calc-table.tpl.php` to your theme folder and edit the footer part to :

```
<tfoot>

<?php if ($view->query->pager->plugin_name != 'none' ): ?>

  <?php foreach ($sub_totals as $type => $row): ?>
    <tr class="view-subfooter-number">
      <?php foreach ($row as $field => $content): ?>
        <td class="view-subfooter views-field views-field-<?php print $fields[$field]; ?>  <?php print $options['info'][$field]['align'] ?>">
          <?php print $content; ?>
        </td>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

<? endif; ?>

  <?php foreach ($totals as $type => $row): ?>
    <tr class="view-footer-number">
      <?php foreach ($row as $field => $content): ?>
        <td class="view-footer views-field views-field-<?php print $fields[$field]; ?>  <?php print $options['info'][$field]['align'] ?>">
          <?php print $content; ?>
        </td>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

</tfoot>
```

the line `if ($view->query->pager->plugin_name != 'none' ):` means that it shows the page sum row only the views uses one of the pager plugins.

This way you are not relying on CSS and you can still use the page sum row when using a pager.